# IAM Policy isn't allowing EC2 access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I have a policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1429817158000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

That is attached to a group. That group has one user. When I log in to myloginthing.signin.aws.amazon.com with that user's credentials I can't do anything related to EC2. It gives me messages such as "*You are not authorized to describe Running Instances*" for every action on the page.

the IAM Policy Simulator tells me any action is denied because

> Implicitly denied (no matching statements found).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This actually took me a while to figure out.

It turns out that you have to match each action (in your example, `ec2:*`) with a set of allowable resources (in your example, `arn:aws:ec2:*`).

The problem is that not every action has the same set of allowable resources - so while you can use a number of different resources for RunInstances, DescribeInstances ONLY supports *.

The whole list is available [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-supported-iam-actions-resources.html)

(Note:  Link is posted because a) the list is very large, and b) it will probably change significantly over time.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain how you got from that link that RunInstances only supports * instead of arn:aws:ec2:*?

Comment: RunInstances has a number of resources - it is DescribeInstances that only supports *.  Under the "Important" section on the page, the first sentence is "If an Amazon EC2 API action is not listed in this table, then it does not support resource-level permissions."  There is also a link to a page with a list of "Unsupported Resource-Level Permissions".

Answer (score 2):

It's actually fine to use `ec2:*` as Allow Action, but `"arn:aws:ec2:*"` is an invalid Amazon Resource Name.

Replace `"arn:aws:ec2:*"` with `"arn:aws:ec2:::*"` or just `"*"` should work.

See [Amazon Resource Names (ARNs) and AWS Service Namespaces](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html)

Comment: I don't think that's true. `arn:aws:ec2:::*` results in `An error occurred: Resource arn:aws:ec2:::* contains an invalid region for vendor ec2.` when I attempt to save the policy. `arn:aws:ec2:*:*:*` will save but doesn't fix anything.

Comment: @Philip try add your region in it, e.g. `arn:aws:ec2:us-west-1::*` (only the last part, aka path can use `*` wildcard)

Answer (score 0):

You have to fill out all Resources:

[image]

```
                arn:aws:ec2:*::image/*
                arn:aws:ec2:*::snapshot/*
                arn:aws:ec2:*:*:subnet/*
                arn:aws:ec2:*:*:network-interface/*
                arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*
                arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*
                arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*
                arn:aws:ec2:*:*:network-interface/*
                arn:aws:ec2:*:*:key-pair/*
```